# Drupal Search API Placeholder && Front Page?

Tags: theming, search

I'm trying to get some placeholder text working for the Search API form, but have a different placeholder on the front page. Here's what I have so far which does work everywhere...

```
function THEME_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['search_api_views_fulltext'])) {
    $form['search_api_views_fulltext']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Search Text here...');
  }
}
```

How can I get this working on only the front page, with a different placeholder text on all other pages? I've tried many things and totally stumped at the moment. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for [`drupal_is_front_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7)

> **Return value**
>
> Boolean value: TRUE if the current page is the front page; FALSE if
>   otherwise.

```
function THEME_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['search_api_views_fulltext']) && drupal_is_front_page()) {
    $form['search_api_views_fulltext']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Search Text here...');
  }
}
```